# Adding entries to hash

Tags: ruby

I am working on a ruby tutorial and came across this. I need to write a method to get this test passed.

```
it 'can add whole entries with keyword and definition' do
    @d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')
    @d.entries.should == {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}
    @d.keywords.should == ['fish']
end
```

How do you add a key value pair to a hash if you pass `'fish' => 'aquatic animal'` instead of  `{'fish' => 'aquatic animal'}`? The pair without `{}` is not an object, so I can't assign it to a variable or use any method to manipulate it.

**UPDATE:**

I am supposed to have a class Dictionary, which has an instance variable `@entries` (initialize as an empty hash), and a method `Dictionary#add` which will add hashes to `@entries`.

So I have made my method like this.
    def add(hash)
      @entries.merge! hash
    end
But obviously this is not merging my empty hash with the hash I need to add.

In the test, `@d` is an instance of Dictionary.

**Solved**

Sorry guys... I just found out I made this mistake forgetting to use bang `!` when I merge. Thanks for helping!

Comment: What test framework is that? What is `@d`?

Comment: *The pair without {} is not an object* It is an object, in fact. Ruby is simply letting you omit the braces in this case, but its a hash all the same. What is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ruby, the curly braces are optional for a Hash passed as the last argument passed to a method. To quote [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Hash.html):

> Hashes are also commonly used as a way to have named parameters in functions...If a hash is the last argument on a method call, no braces are needed

That is, if you have the method:

```
def foo(name, hash)
  puts "The keys in this hash are #{hash.keys.inspect}"
end
```

You could invoke it as:

```
foo("test", {"a" => 1, "b" => 2})
```

Or as:

```
foo("test", "a" => 1, "b" => 2)
```

In both cases, Ruby will correctly interpret the final argument as a Hash.

In your case, `@d.add('fish' => 'aquatic animal')` and `@d.add({'fish' => 'aquatic animal'})` are synonymous.